SAS Macro to iterate proc freq using a list
I have a dataset where I have to run frequencies on a dozen variables for a dozen organizations. This is very easy with proc print but I don't want to have to update the WHERE statement a dozen times to run each of the frequencies so I am hoping to simplify this with a macro.
As an example, we can use the sashelp.cars dataset where it runs a frequency for two variables (for simplicity) by each auto maker.
I wrote a macro hoping to iterate a simple proc freq like the following except the macro would iterate through the list of auto makers "make" in the WHERE statement and run the assigned frequencies.
proc freq data=sashelp.cars; 
    table Type DriveTrain;
    where make = "Honda";
run;

Here is the macro I wrote:
%macro car_freq(dataset, n_make);
    %do i = 1 %to &n_make;
        %let maker =  %scan(make., &i);

        title "&maker";
    proc freq data=&dataset;
        where make = "&maker";
        tables type DriveTrain;
    run;
title;
%end;
%mend car_freq;

%car_freq(sashelp.cars, 38)

When I run the macro, it runs without errors but says that there are 0 observations for each iteration. What am I missing to get this to iterate through the list of makers and run the frequencies for the two variables?

You can Sort the data and use BY statement.
proc sort data=sashelp.cars out=cars;
  by make;
run;

ods html file='report.html';

  options byline;
  title;
  proc freq data=cars;
    by make;
    tables type drivetrain;
    where make in: ('L');
  run; 

ods html close;

Will output


Oh wow did I over complicate that! Thank you!!
